# nested queries in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am querying 3 collection one inside another and getting the desired result.But problem is I am getting can't set headers after they are sent.I think I made some mistake in redirecting route.Please help me out.

Here is my code :

```js
Supervisor.findOneAndRemove({ email: req.params.email }).then((supervisor) => {
            supervisor.proposals.forEach(function(i) {
                Student.findOneAndRemove({proposal_id : i}).then((student) => {
                    ProjectSubmit.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: i },
                        { "$set": { "pending": true, "status": "Not Started",
                        "supervisorName": "Supervisor name will be added here when proposal is accepted"}},
                        function(err, projectSubmit) 
                        {
                           console.log("inside proposal");
                               if (err) {
                                   console.log(err);
                                   return res.send(err);
                               } 
                               console.log("done");
                                //res.redirect('/remove-supervisors');
                               
                        });
                });
            });
            res.redirect('/remove-supervisors');
        });
```

Comment: Not sure but add a `return` at each end of a condition. If there is some middleware that call `next()` in the process that's maybe the cause of the error.

Comment: tried,didn't work!